# How can a webpage listen to POST response sent by 3rd party

Tags: javascript, html, post, cybersource

I have a SPA using HTML and JS.
It is having an iFrame which goes to 3rd party service (Cardinal) to do some authentication and return the session to a configurable returnURL field (Here http://127.0.0.1:8080) this is where my application is running.

I see in the network console of chrome the request received

> Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
>
> Request Method: POST Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed Remote
> Address: 127.0.0.1:8080
>
> Form data: TransactionId=txnId&Response=&MD=null

I need to understand how can my page listen to this POST and get the txnId value.

This is the link to cardinal implementation example
https://developer.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Payer_Authentication_SCMP_API/html/index.html#t=Topics%2FProcess_Flow_for_Cardinal_Cruise_Direct_Connection_API.htm%23TOC_Receiving_the_Step_Upbc-17&rhtocid=_4_2_3_1

What I tried is attaching windom.addEventListener for message and check for origin 127.0.0.1 but it is not receiving in this way.

Update:
This is for 3D Secure (3DS) implementation, here the iframe will be from issuing bank asking for a security challenge question or OTP, once user submits the value in iframe, we receive the transactionId as part of the POST response to the returnURL/callback URL.
From here we need to send back this transaction id to our server for making the final auth call.

Comment: HTML & (client-side) JS alone can not work with incoming POST data at all.

Comment: _"The merchantURL page serves as a listening URL."_ - I would assume that they mean what is commonly referred to as a _callback URL_ here. Which means this is not even about things happening on the client side; but that their server will make a request to your server, which you will have to process accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Responsibility for confirming that payment has been made needs to be given to your server, not the user's browser.

Comment: TransactionId={{txnId}} that we receive as part of this POST response is required to be sent back to our server for final auth call to make the transaction successful.